# How to Implement Canvas Brightness/Contrast in Safari 17?

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, html5-canvas

I'm facing an issue with drawing multiple images on a canvas with varying levels of brightness in Safari 17.
I know that `CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter` is not supported in Safari,
but I need to achieve this effect for my project.

Here's a snippet of the code that works in other browsers but not in Safari:

```
ctx.filter = 'brightness(' + el.exposure + ')';
ctx.drawImage(this.carbonImage, el.x, el.y, 224, 263);
ctx.filter = 'none';
```

Is there any workaround or alternative approach that can help me to adapt this code for Safari?

Any help would be appreciated!